# Blaze can not tackle with BIGINT, TEXT data structure of postgresql database

Tags: blaze

I am trying Blaze to analyze data in my postgres db

connecting use

```
conn_string = 'postgresql://postgres:mysecretpassword@localhost:5432/postgres'
Data(resource(conn_string, schema='public'))
```

it gives the error

```
Blaze does not understand a SQLAlchemy type.
Blaze provided the following error:
No SQL-datashape match for type HSTORE
Skipping.

Blaze does not understand a SQLAlchemy type.
Blaze provided the following error:
No SQL-datashape match for type TEXT[]
Skipping.

Blaze does not understand a SQLAlchemy type.
Blaze provided the following error:
No SQL-datashape match for type BIGINT[]
Skipping.
```

It seems that Blaze can not understand the data type of my postgresql